# Дублируются буквы и цифры при вводе на клавиатуре, сижу я на arch linux

Tags: linux, archlinux

купил себе ноутбук и поставил arch linux, столкнулся с такой проблемой что при вводе буквы у меня она дублируется и долго вводиться пример: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqgggggggggggggg, я не знаю с чем это связанно, но я подключил внешнею клавиатуру и все нормально, помогите, если нужно будет подробная информация то предоставлю

Answer (score 0):

У меня подобное поведение было на ноутбуке модели 2023г. Перепробовал разные дистрибутивы и оконные менеджеры - ничего не помогало. Причем на windows 10 клавиатура отрабатывала как надо. Проблема ушла лишь с откатом к ядру linux 5.10 На этом ядре и Fn клавиша отрабатывает как надо и никаких залипаний-повторений.
Система - AMD Ryzen 5 5560U; ОС - Manjaro Gnome